# Mobile App Links handled differently across channels

Tags: android, ios, web, url, deep-linking

I'm curious to understand why the same link (example below) would perform differently depending on how it's opened. Is anyone able to help clarify?

Link: https://mywebsite/home

When the above link is sent in an email the link usually opens in a browser. However, when the link is on a webpage and clicked it usually opens up in the corresponding app.

Are there any options available to help make the performance more consistent?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using universal links on iOS?

Comment: Hi, no, we're not.

Comment: if you use universal links this will be the same on all applications on iOS, I have verified this.

Comment: Thanks @Satheeshwaran, but do you know why it currently has the nuances? I'm just trying to understand why an email and a webpage would handle the exact same link differently.

Comment: Usually, email providers add URL protection to links in email, this is common across enterprise email providers like Exchange/outlook that could be one of the reaons this could happen.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to open the link from e.g. email in your app, you can read about deep linking in Android. I`m sure it will help you :)